# input content value is not showing on front end

Tags: html

I have this code that I receive from database a formated data of a social security number.

```html
<div class="col-md-3">
  <h5>Social Security #:<span class="text-danger">*</span></h5>
  <div class="controls">
    <div id="show-create">
      <input type="number" id="social-security" name="social-security" class="form-control" value="123-45-6789">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

When I check Element on Chrome, I have the `value="123-45-6789"`, but is not showing on front end.

Comment: `123-45-67891` is not a valid `type="number"`.

Comment: ... which you should also have gotten a warning about in the browser console, `The specified value "123-45-6789" cannot be parsed, or is out of range.`

Comment: i  have this number stored on database at that pattern 123-12-1234, but i want to show it as same patter to.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

HTML input with `type='number'` only allow numeric values such as `50`, `-10`, or `-45.3`. Since your input value `123-45-6789` contains a dash in the middle, it's not a numeric value but a string. Change the input type from number to text, and it will work.

From

```
type="number"
```

To

```
type="text"
```

Full code

```html
<div class="col-md-3">
  <h5>Social Security #:<span class="text-danger">*</span></h5>
  <div class="controls">
    <div id="show-create">
      <?php  foreach ($peoples as $row) { ?>
      <input type="text" id="social-security" name="social-security" class="form-control" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars ($row['social-security'])?>">
      <?php  } ?>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You have an `<input type="number">`, which is used only for numbers.  But `"123-45-6789"` is not a number:

```html
<input type="number" value="123-45-6789">
```

Since you're trying to display a text value, use an `<input type="text">` instead:

```html
<input type="text" value="123-45-6789">
```

Basically, just because text *contains number characters* does not mean that it *is a number*.  Social security numbers, phone numbers, address components, etc.

Comment: Great! tha's it. Works great, sorry i am new on this!!